# Unable to render loaded javascript resources at browser in Angular and Spring Boot application

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, mime-types, content-type

I am working on Angular + Spring Boot application with JAR packaging. Frontend code is in the resources/public directory in the backend project.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class GleeOMeterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GleeOMeterApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class AngularWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("{path:^(?!(?:oauth|api|index.html)).*$}/**").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    public ResourceServerConfiguration(CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.customAuthenticationEntryPoint = customAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("api");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/signin**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/signin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/glee**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/api/users**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint).accessDeniedHandler(new CustomAccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.reliqs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-glee-o-meter-2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-glee-o-meter</name>
    <description>REST backend for glee-o-meter application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>12</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/public</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>../glee-o-meter/dist/glee-o-meter</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>*.gz</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Glee-O-Meter</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Project Structure: You can see frontend code files in resources/public directory.
[image]

Error which is coming while running the application from browser:

[image]

All HTTP requests are passed with 200 status.
[image]

What I have understood by searching on Google for hours is that this issue is because of `content-type` in response header is text/html but the file is javascript file so can't be rendered at browser because of X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff.

Can anyone help to resolve this issue, please? I have tried many ways suggested in Google search but they didn't work.

Please mention in comments if any other information required from my side.

Comment: Looks like you have security enabled and your requests are returning the login page. Check what's actually being returned in those erroneous requests.

Comment: Yes @TheHeadRush security is enabled but I have disabled default form login and returning custom login page written in angular code.

Comment: And because you are not yet authenticated, you are probably getting the login page (or `index.html`) back in each of those requests. Hence the checking what's actually in the response bit i mentioned above. You'll need to allow unauthenticated requests for javascript files.

Comment: @TheHeadRush thank you for your suggestion. However I tried ignoring static contents from spring security but didn't work. Even I removed spring security still the same issue. This seems to be content-type issue. DispatcherServlet sets text/html content-type by default but JS files needs text/javascript that's why js files are successfully fetched at browser but not rendered by browser. You can see in image of JS requests in attached image.